# Where is the Question mark in VirtualKey Enum?

Tags: uwp

To handle user key presses, I use CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args) event.

But few keys seem to be missing in the enum name list, one of them is the Question mark (?). Is there a different name for that key?

Comment: There is no question mark key. There is a slash key that makes a question mark if you press it in combination with the shift key. The slash key (with a question mark) is [VK_OEM_2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).

Answer (score 0):

Though I could not find the enum name for the question mark, I found a solution to my issue, I got the following debug output from that event on pressing the '?' symbol.

"VirtualKey = 191"